# Can QR-code be generated and exported to pdf without rendering it to html in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, qr-code

I want to export QR-code to pdf using `jsPDF` without showing it in html. I tried so many libraries- `qrcode`, `angularx-qrcode`.

Comment: Why you want to skip HTML part? Get image source -> add it as base64 encoded `<img>` -> convert to PDF

Comment: Finding and using JS libraries in Angular can be tricky. Could you post what you have attempted to do with jsPDF in your Angular code? Your question is very general and it's difficult to assist unless you've posted some code showing what you have attempted - consider making a stackblitz at Stackblitz.com of your code.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [ngx-qrcode](https://github.com/techiediaries/ngx-qrcode) to generate the QR code. And from there embed the QR code in your template and retreive it back and print it. The QR code is still in the DOM, but it can be hidden using CSS. Try the following

Component

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  qrvalue = 'embedded qr';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL;
  }

  download() {
    const qrcode = document.getElementById('qrcode');
    let doc = new jsPDF();

    let imageData= this.getBase64Image(qrcode.firstChild.firstChild);
    doc.addImage(imageData, "JPG", 10, 10);

    doc.save('FirstPdf.pdf');
  }
}
```

Template

```
<div class="container">
  <ngx-qrcode id="qrcode" [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}"  [qrc-element-type]="'img'" [qrc-value]="qrvalue">
  </ngx-qrcode>
  <button (click)="download()" class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</button>
</div>
```

**Explanation for `firstChild.firstChild`**

Structure of the `ngx-qrcode` in DOM is as follows

```
<ngx-qrcode _ngcontent-c2="" id="qrcode" style="display: block;" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-element-type="img" ng-reflect-value="embedded qr">
  <div class="qrcode">\
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...">
  </div>
</ngx-qrcode>
```

So we use `document.getElementById('qrcode').firstChild.firstChild` to retrieve the `img` tag that contains the QR code.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-fpmqwp)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Your explanation was very clear.

Comment: Hello, I am following a similar mechanism to download qr codes as a ZIP. in my case, there can be multiple QR codes. When downloading, the same QR gets downloaded. Even if I change the QR content in a loop, I dont think the change has an effect to the QR in the DOM. Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: I created a stackblitz for this. There I add 3 qr codes in 3 pages. But all three are same.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-tnz5d6?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: You are pushing the elements in the pdf in a for loop and save method is called outside of it. So for loop continues its iteration and save method is called before the loop ends.  You need to write a logic inside forloop for save method. This happened with me too.