# Changing content of the QR code from component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, qr-code

I am using **ngx-qrcode2** for generating QR codes in my angular application. There what I need to do is attach a set of QR codes to a PDF and download the file.

I change the content of the QR in component in a loop. in my DOM I see the qr code changes when the loop runs.

```
fruits = ['mango', 'apple', 'orange']

async download() {

    let doc = new jsPDF();

    let imgDataArr = [];

    for (const f of this.fruits) {
      this.qrvalue = f;

      while (!document.querySelector(".qrcode img")) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
        console.log("waiting for qr");
      }
      console.log("QR element is available");

      const qrcode = document.getElementById('qrcode');

      let imageData= this.getBase64Image(qrcode.firstChild.firstChild);

      imgDataArr.push(imageData)
    } 

    for (const data of imgDataArr ) {

      doc.addImage(data, "JPG", 10, 10);   
       doc.addPage();
    }

    doc.save('FirstPdf.pdf');
}
```

However, the final PDF I download contains three QR codes with same data in it.

Why is that? Is there a delay before the element changes? How to fix this?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-tnz5d6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Note that, my implementation is largely based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755612/3892439).